# PowerShell как запускать скрипт через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: windows, powershell

PowerShell как запускать скрипт через определенный промежуток времени.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно я не правильно понял вопрос, но в Windows есть "Планировщик заданий" , в который можно добавить скрипт и указать необходимый интервал запуска. [Вот тут](http://tavalik.ru/sozdanie-novoy-zadachi-v-windows-server-2008-r2/) более подробно расписано (на примере Windows Server 2008R2).